# Print ALL common parts between 2 strings

Tags: php

As the title says I need to get the longest common substring between 2 strings. The problem is that I also need to print **ALL** common parts if there's more than one. Example:

$string1 = "asbafbae**MATCH1**asjdndrey**MATCH2**";

$string2 = "12412342gt**MATCH1**hgm1g5m**MATCH2**";

Needed output: MATCH1, MATCH2

This is the code I'm using, I managed to get the longest common substring but just one.

```
<?php
function getLongestMatchingSubstring($str1, $str2)
{
    $len_1 = strlen($str1);
    $longest = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $len_1; $i++){
        for($j = $len_1 - $i; $j > 0; $j--){
            $sub = substr($str1, $i, $j);
            if (strpos($str2, $sub) !== false && strlen($sub) > strlen($longest)){
                $longest = $sub;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $longest;
}

$string1 = 'asbafbaeMATCH1asjdndreyMATCH2';
$string2 = '12412342gtMATCH1hgm1g5mMATCH2';
echo getLongestMatchingSubstring($string1, $string2);
?>
```

With that I get **MATCH1** as output. Maybe the code I'm writing is specifically to get the longest one. Hope someone can help me

Comment: Keep an array of the matches. When you find a match, check if it's the same length or longer than the array elements. If it's longer, empty the array and add the new match. If it's the same length, just add the new match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your function to get longest matches in array

```
<?php
function getLongestMatchingSubstring($str1, $str2)
{
    $len_1 = strlen($str1);
    $longest = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $len_1; $i++){
        for($j = $len_1 - $i; $j > 0; $j--){
            $sub = substr($str1, $i, $j);
            if (strpos($str2, $sub) !== false && strlen($sub) > 1){
                $longest[] = $sub;
                $i = strpos($str1, $sub) + (strlen($sub)-1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $longest;
}

$string1 = 'asbaMbaeMATCH1asjdndreyMATCH22r5g7jdg3MATCH33';
$string2 = '1241M342gtMAThgMATCH1m1g5mMATCH2cghdiMATCH33';
print_r(getLongestMatchingSubstring($string1, $string2));
```

the output would be

Array([0] => M [1] => MATCH1 [2] => MATCH2 [3] => MATCH33 )

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. But somehow it only works when you put the matching words in the same order in the string vars, otherwise it only shows just one matching word. Example: If $str1 = "123Example" and "$str2 = Example123" it only shows "123" as common words. Do I need to code it in a different way? Anyway thank you so much, I'm a step closer to what I need.

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake calculating the $i offset which should be for $str1, I modified the code so it would fix that issue and changed the condition so it will not show single character match.